# No query registered for suggest

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query

I am using Elasticsearch **5.5**. I am setting my mapping like this.

```
{
    '_id': false,
    '_isForeignField': true,
    '_schemaType': 'signatory',
    'es_indexed': true,
    'mapping': {
      properties : {
        canonicalName : {
          type: 'text'
        },
        'canonicalName-suggest': { type: 'completion' }
      }
    }
  }
```

My query declaration is

```
const query = {
      index: this.getIndexName(),
      body: {
        query: { bool: { must: [], should: [], 'must_not': [] } },
        _source: false
      }
    };
```

This is the query that calls elasticsearch.

```
should.bool.should.push({
                suggest:{
                  canonicalNameSuggester : {
                    prefix : filterVal, 
                    completion : { 
                      field : 'canonicalName' 
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
```

I am new to the Elasticsearch concept. I am getting the error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [suggest]","line":1,"col":126}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [suggest]","line":1,"col":126},"status":400}'
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide ur ES query in JSON format?

Comment: query:  {"index":"gazebo-company","body":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"group":["5de6fad3f7ee821a45e8379e"]}}]}},{"bool":{"should":[{"suggest":{"canonicalNameSuggester":{"prefix":"l","completion":{"field":"canonicalName"}}}}]}}],"should":[],"must_not":[]}},"_source":true,"size":"50"}}

Comment: Thanks for json query, I want to repro ur issue, but for that I need your index setting and mapping JSON as well

Comment: Json is a big file to paste here. I am trying to acheive autocomplete functionality in the canonicalName property. Here is the mapping until that. "gazebo-contact": {"mappings": {"contact": {"properties": {"_meta": {"properties": {"commentCount": {"type": "long" }  } },
                    "age": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "canonicalName": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "untouched": {
                                "type": "keyword"}}},

Comment: sure let me hv a look

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. You are trying a suggest query on the text field 'canonicalName'. If you are only trying to do match query then you need to change the query.